# Persistent Variable Issue: Incorrect Texture Index in C++/Opengl Rendering

Tags: opengl, c++, 2d, shaders, graphics

I am attempting to render two different textures in C++/OpenGL. However, I am encountering an issue where the integer I pass as the **texture index** to my **Fragment Shader** always seems to be set to **0**. In the Fragment Shader's commented code, you can see that I tried to retrieve the correct texture from the sampler2D by using the texture index passed from **Vertex Shader**. However, this approach did not work as expected, **as it always displayed the texture bound to** **slot 0**. To debug this issue, I added an "if" statement to check if v_textureIndex is assigned the correct values, but it appears that it is always set to **0**, resulting in a red quads being displayed on my screen. I am unsure of what the problem could be. I'm really suprised by that as my all other values seems to work correctly. Initially, to fix this, **I attempted to use a float variable** for texture index, but it **exhibited the same behavior**.

I checked if

1. quadVertices array values with debugger to ensure that 2 quads (8 vertices) have proper value, especially the texture index
2. glEnableVertexArrayAttrib, glVertexArrayAttribFormat, glVertexArrayAttribBinding should be all correct, especially that other values that I pass right
3. Added glGetError() after every gl call but that didn't helped.
4. When I modified it to use float instead of int I tried to add **flat** modifier too, but that didn't changed nothing.

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 a_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 a_color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 a_textureCoords;
layout (location = 3) in int a_textureIndex;

uniform mat4 u_transform;
uniform mat4 u_viewProjectionMatrix;

out vec4 v_color;
out vec2 v_textureCoords;
flat out int v_textureIndex;

void main()
{
    v_color = a_color;
    v_textureIndex = a_textureIndex;
    v_textureCoords = a_textureCoords;
    gl_Position = u_viewProjectionMatrix * u_transform * vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 460

in vec4 v_color;
in vec2 v_textureCoords;
flat in int v_textureIndex;

uniform sampler2D u_textures[64];
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    if (v_textureIndex == 0)
    {
        color = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    else if (v_textureIndex == 1)
    {
        color = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    }

    //color = v_color * texture(u_textures[int(v_textureIndex)], v_textureCoords);
}
```

**Draw method**

```
void Renderer::draw(Reference<Sprite> sprite, int index)
{
    sprite->getTexture()->bind(index);

    m_sceneData->textureShader->bind();
    m_sceneData->textureShader->uploadUniformMatrix4("u_transform", sprite->getMatrix());
    m_sceneData->textureShader->uploadUniformMatrix4("u_viewProjectionMatrix", m_sceneData->viewProjectionMatrix);

    FloatRect textureRect = (FloatRect)sprite->getTextureRect();
    textureRect.x /= sprite->getTexture()->getSize().x;
    textureRect.y /= sprite->getTexture()->getSize().y;
    textureRect.width /= sprite->getTexture()->getSize().x;
    textureRect.height /= sprite->getTexture()->getSize().y;

    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 0].position = { 0.0f, 1.0f }; // bottom right
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 1].position = { 1.0f, 0.0f }; // top right
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 2].position = { 0.0f, 0.0f }; // top left
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 3].position = { 1.0f, 1.0f }; // bottom right

    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 0].color = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 1].color = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 2].color = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 3].color = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 0].textureCoords = { textureRect.width, textureRect.y }; // top right
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 1].textureCoords = { textureRect.x, textureRect.height }; // bottom left
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 2].textureCoords = { textureRect.width, textureRect.height }; // bottom right
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 3].textureCoords = { textureRect.x, textureRect.y }; // top left

    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 0].textureIndex = index;
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 1].textureIndex = index;
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 2].textureIndex = index;
    m_sceneData->quadVertices[m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount + 3].textureIndex = index;

    m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount += 4u;
    m_sceneData->quadVertexBuffer->setData((void*)(m_sceneData->quadVertices.data()), m_sceneData->quadVerticesCount * sizeof(SceneData::QuadVertex));

    glBindVertexArray(m_sceneData->quadVertexArray->getRendererID());
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_sceneData->quadVertexArray->getIndexBuffer()->getCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
}
```

**QuadVertex struct**

```
struct QuadVertex
{
    Vector2f position;
    Vector4f color;
    Vector2f textureCoords;
    int textureIndex;
};
```

Draw calls (no, I'm not passing 'index' as 0 twice lmao)

```
Renderer::draw(m_sprite, 0);
Renderer::draw(m_sprite2, 1);
```

Current output with plain colors
[image]

Current output with texture (if I first render second texture, the second texture is displayed twice)
[image]